# Accessing elements using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to access name from the below json and view it using backbone.js.

```
[
        {
            "name": "Sii",
            "eid": "E3",
            "subdomain": "PS"
        },

        {
            "name": "Shalini",
            "eid": "E8",
            "subdomain": "H"
        },
        {
            "name": "Priya",
            "eid": "E3",
            "subdomain": "HG"
        }
    ]
```

I wan to access the name by using the eid.and render it in view .

Answer (score 0):

Goto Backbonejs.org and read basic concepts there. Everything is explanatory with examples.

To brief

- You need to define a model with attributes name,eid,subdomain Create
- collection which contain that model and uri to the file containing
- json call .fetch() on collection

Now you can iterate over collection and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty vague question. You have actually asked how to implement backbone models and collections for use.

One way to get the value using eid is

```
var data = [
        {
            "name": "Sii",
            "eid": "E3",
            "subdomain": "PS"
        },

        {
            "name": "Shalini",
            "eid": "E8",
            "subdomain": "H"
        },
        {
            "name": "Priya",
            "eid": "E3",
            "subdomain": "HG"
        }
    ];
var coll = new Collection(data);
```

For getting the name by eid:

```
model = coll.findWhere({'eid':"E8"});
var name = model.get('name');
```